# spring configure 2D double array

Tags: java, xml, arrays, spring

I have two properties
int[][] int2Darray;
double[][] dounle2Darray;

in xml for int array: works fine

```
<property name="int2Darray">
    <array>
        <value>0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0</value>
        <value>0, 0, 66, 31, 1, 1, 1</value>
    </array>
</property>
```

in xml for double array

```
<property name="double2Darray">
    <array>
        <value>27.0, 45.5, 21.0, 4.0, 2.0, 0.5</value>
        <value>22.5, 42.0, 24.0, 7.0, 3.5, 1.0</value>
    </array>
</property>
```

This produce exception during bean initialization: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "27.0,45.5,21.0,4.0,2.0,0.5"

The possible solution, i've found:

```
<property name="double2Darray">
    <array>
        <array>
            <value>27.0</value>
            <value>45.5</value>
            <value>21.0</value>
        </array>           
    </array>
</property>
```

But, this solution make xml configuration unreadable. I have about 20 subarrays.

Is there any possibility to make spring parse string as double array?

Comment: Maybe it works when you put brackets around it, like `<value>[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]</value>`?

Comment: brackets didn't help: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.Object[]' to required type 'double[][]' for property 'double2Darray'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[33.0,48.5,16.0,1.0,1.0,0.5]"